# How to map two objects data and extract the details from one?

Tags: javascript

In one of my project, I've requirement to map two objects as follows:

```
const artistData = [
{
   "_id":"abc123",
   "name":"John Sams",
   "age" : 35
},
{
   "_id":"pqr123",
   "name":"John Adams",
   "age" : 45
},
{
   "_id":"abc455",
   "name":"Patrick",
   "age" : 39
},
{
   "_id":"xyz345",
   "name":"Matt Hardy",
   "age" : 43
}

]

const messageData = [
{
"artistId": "xyz345",
"message": "Hello Matt!!!"
}
]
```

Here I want to map artist_id of 'artistData' and artistId of 'messageData' in order to extract data from the first object array. I have used following method:

```
artistData.some(artistId => artistId._id === messageData.artistId)
```

What could be the best possible solution?

Comment: You need `.find()` instead of `.some()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#common_operations

Comment: I think you need two for loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the exact requirement you're being asked to fulfill? Are you trying to get all messages belonging to a particular artist? There will be a different answer depending on what exactly you're trying to do.

For example, if you started with an artist `someArtist` and you wanted all of the messages sent to them, you could do something like this:

```js
messageData.filter(message => message.artistId === someArtist._id)
```

If you started with a message `someMessage` and you wanted the artist it was sent to, you could do something like this:

```js
artistData.find(artist => artist._id === someMessage.artistId)
```

### Edit

If you want to add the name of artist to the message you could do something like this:

```js
const messageWithArtistName = {
  ...someMessage, 
  name: artistData.find(artist => artist._id === someMessage.artistId).name}
}
```

Note that this will fail if you don't find a matching artist

### Edited Again

If you wanted to do that will all messages.

```js
messageData.map(message => {...message, name: artistData.find(artist => artist._id === message.artistId).name })
```

Comment: OK but, how will you extract that data which is required?

Comment: `const myData = artistData.find(artist => artist._id === someMessage.artistId)` now myData is an object with expected data

Comment: More information about exactly what you're trying to do would be helpful.

Comment: are you trying to get the name of the artist that the message is to and add it to the object?

Comment: Thanks for the response... Well in my React component I want only data of Matt Hardy like his name, age etc by mapping its id

Comment: In a component like  <div>{artisData.find(artist => artist._id === someMessage.artistId)}</div> and then map or something like that

Comment: You are almost near it

Answer (score 0):

A better approach is to do the opposite.

Let's first loop though the messages using `.forEach()` and for every single message try to find the artist, we're gonna use the `.find()` array method

```js
const artists = [
{ id: "19823908109", name: "Johnas Smith", age: 44 },
{ id: "00823933109", name: "Jane Doe",     age: 19 },
{ id: "30823908109", name: "Mary Air",     age: 20 },
{ id: "58239081091", name: "Tom Silver",   age: 87 },
];

const messages = [
{ id: "58239081091", message: "Hello World" },
{ id: "30823908109", message: "Hi, Tom!" }
];



// Loop through every single message
messages.forEach( ({ id, message }) => {

  // Find the artist
  const artist = artists.find( artist => artist.id === id );
  
  // Log the artist
  console.log(artist)
});
```